# Extract first numeric part of field

Tags: sql, postgresql, split, numeric

I have a database (Postgres 7.4) field for address

Example Data

```
    address            |    zip
-----------------------+-------------+
123 main street        |    12345
-----------------------+-------------+
3 where road           |    12345
-----------------------+-------------+
South 3 where road     |    12345
```

The queries

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE zip = 12345
AND address ILIKE '3%'
```

I get all but I don't want 123 main street

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE zip = 12345
AND address ILIKE '123%'
```

I get the results I want

My question is how do I just match the numeric part of the address?

Comment: Does postgre support `REGEX`? I know MySQL does, but I'm not so sure when it comes to postgre.

Comment: yes but this is an older version of Postgres so it my be limited http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wasn't exactly sure. Just a thought - if you're just trying to match a fixed numeric, why not just do your second query? Or are you looking for rows with(out) numerics at the start?

Comment: Also, consider upgrading to a more recent version. 7.4 is **ancient**.

Comment: yep we are it's just this needs to be fixed now and we are running 7.4, ugh...

Comment: @Polynomial: Ain't [no such thing as "postgre"](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Postgres).

Comment: Apologies, I'm in the habit of calling it "postgre" because of someone at work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT substring(address, '^\\d+') AS heading_number
FROM   tbl
WHERE  zip = 12345
AND    address ILIKE '3%'
```

Returns 1 or more digits from the start of the string.
Leave out the anchor `^` if you want the *first sequence of digits* in the string instead of the *sequence at the start*. Example:

```
SELECT substring('South 13rd street 3452435 foo', '\\d+');
```

Read about [`substring()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) and [regular expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) in the manual.
In more recent versions (8.0+, with `standard_conforming_strings = on`), use [escape string syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html) like this:

```
SELECT substring('South 13rd street 3452435 foo', E'\\d+');
```

Or just:

```
SELECT substring('South 13rd street 3452435 foo', '\d+');
```

Comment: I get type "e" does not exist. If I remove the E it seems to work, still testing

Comment: @PhillPafford: Ah, `E` for [escape string syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html) was intruduced with 8.0 (I think), just leave it out

Comment: Would this still work if a word is in front of the numeric value, like South 3rd street?

Comment: @PhillPafford: See amended answer.

Comment: this does not work when an address goes like FLAT 3. does not extract the 3

Comment: @Luffydude: 'FLAT 3' is not *supposed* to qualify with `ILIKE '3%'`, which only includes *leading* patterns. You can ask a new question with your exact environment and requirements.

Comment: just did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936348/how-to-select-the-first-number-in-a-string