# Find Match in Database within the Field

Tags: sql, postgresql

Part two of this question:

- [Extract first numeric part of field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143581/extract-first-numeric-part-of-field)

NOTE: I'm running Postgres 7.4 and yes we are upgrading

Example Data

```
    address            |    zip
-----------------------+-------------+
123 main street        |    12345
-----------------------+-------------+
23 where road          |    12345
-----------------------+-------------+
South 23 where lane    |    12345
```

The query

```
SELECT address
FROM tbl
WHERE zip = 12345
AND LOWER(substring(address, '^\\w+')) = LOWER('lane')
```

Also tried

```
SELECT address
FROM tbl
WHERE zip = 12345
AND LOWER(substring(address, '\\w+')) = LOWER('lane')

SELECT address
FROM tbl
WHERE zip = 12345
AND LOWER(substring(address, '^\\w')) = LOWER('lane')

SELECT address
FROM tbl
WHERE zip = 12345
AND LOWER(substring(address, '\\w')) = LOWER('lane')
```

I would like to be able to search for any part of the address in the address column. So if I needed all rows that had the word `lane`, I could pass lane and the zip to return all the rows. This would give me:

```
    address            |    zip
-----------------------+-------------+
South 23 where lane    |    12345
```

Or if I needed all the rows with and address of 23, this would give me:

```
    address            |    zip
-----------------------+-------------+
23 where road          |    12345
-----------------------+-------------+
South 23 where lane    |    12345
```

Is there something I could change in the example query above to allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "all rows that had the word lane". A single regular expression probably isn't going to work here.

```
with tbl as (
    select '123 main street' address, '12345' zip
    union all
    select '23 where road', '12345' zip
    union all
    select 'South 23 where lane', '12345' zip
    union all
    select '245 Meadowlane Dr', '12345'
    union all 
    select '764 Pine Lane Ave', '12345'
)
select * from tbl
where zip = '12345' 
  and (
          address ~* '^lane .*' 
       or address ~* '.* lane .*'
       or address ~* '.* lane$'
      );

address               zip
--
South 23 where lane   12345
764 Pine Lane Ave     12345
```

That kind of regular expression won't return "123 main street" if you use "23" instead of "lane" in the WHERE clause. But it also won't let you query for all the addresses in the 2300 block of Maple St. Apartment numbers and PO Box numbers can also surprise you.

Comment: Testing, I think this might work. And as for the 2300 block I wouldn't want that in the results but good to know. And for PO Boxes I do an additional validation before this one

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could try something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE zip = 12345 
AND (address like '% ' + 'lane' + ' %' -- check in middle 
or address like 'lane' + ' %' -- check at beginning
or address like '% ' + 'lane') -- check at end
```

Bt I'd advise against it.

If you're this far into troubles, you might have better luck looking at "full text search" capabilities, especially since performance isn't going to be great.

I hear the new Postgres has support for that, though.

Comment: If I do this I get this record as well, which I don't want from the second set of queries. 123 main street

Comment: Small bug fixed above. So the second query would become something like:address like '% 23 %' or address like '23 %' or address like '% 23'. That should work. It doesn't?