# How to select the first number in a string

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

Basically I have a big list of addresses that can sometimes start with FLAT "number", "rest of address" or APARTMENT "number", "rest of address" or sometimes even "number"A, "rest of address" or FLAT "number"A.

How to select the first number and if the number has a character then include that as well?

Examples:

- if the address is `FLAT 3, thanos house, nw1 6fs` then I need to select `3`
- if the address is `FLAT 3B, thanos house, nw1 6fs`  then I need to select `3B`
- if the address is `324, thanos house, nw1 6fs`  then I need to select `324`
- if the address is `APARTMENT 324, thanos house, nw1 6fs`  then I need to select `324`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name answer did not work for me, answerer told me to create new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [`substring()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) expression does what you ask:

```
substring(string, '\m\d+\D?*\M')
```

The regular expression only returns the first match, or `NULL` if none.

`\m` ...  [beginning of a word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE)
`\d+`  ... one or more digits
`\D?` ... zero or one non-digits
`\M` ... [end of word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE)

Demo:

```
SELECT string, substring(string, '\d+\D?\d*\M')
FROM  (
   VALUES
  ('FLAT 3, thanos house, nw1 6fs')
, ('FLAT 3B, thanos house, nw1 6fs')
, ('324, thanos house, nw1 6fs')
, ('APARTMENT 324, thanos house, nw1 6fs')
   ) tbl(string);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e8d9236282c150c0422501bbd7ffa672)*

Comment: perfect! first time seeing from (values tbl()) being used too so thanks for that too!

Comment: @Luffydude: [The manual on `VALUES`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-values.html)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter perfect solution! Learnt something new :-)